# Address on move and return

Tags: rust

Let us consider the following rust snippet:

```rust
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        println!("(1) {:p}", &t);  // Print (1)
        
        let this = Self(t);
        println!("(2) {:p}", &this.0);  // Print (2)
        this
    }
}
```

**Note**: let us assume `T` does not implement `Copy` trait for now.

(*For the complete snippet see at the end of the post*)

#### Question 1

Is it *always* true that "print (1)" and "print (2)" are going to display two *different* address?

In other words, move a value *always* implies the change of its address?

#### Question 2

Considering the `new` function returns `Self`. Is the correct terminology saying that "the returned value is *moved*"?

In other words, `this` is going to be *moved* to the caller function?

In that case, why it seems that the address of `this` does not change? RVO is kicking in here?

---

[Rust Playground example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c697a7b6248d590e74888ae75f08650)

Comment: Rust guaranty absolute nothing about all this. As it should be. That implementation behavior. Just try in release mod and see. The very fact you print address of variable change the behavior.

Comment: So moving an object (for a not copyable type) might or might not change the address of the object itself. No guarantee are given by the standard. I would be glad if someone can point me out official material on this matter.

Comment: @BiagioF Why does this matter? The borrow checker is responsible of whether something can be moved or not, it shouldn't be important for to the programmer. What's your context?

Comment: @Finomnis More academic interest I suppose. However, it might matter in case of unsafe code (dealing with pointers, and self-ref structs for example).

Comment: In that case, you should assume that every pass-by-move actually changes the address. There are no guarantees by the compiler that it doesn't. Every move invalidates all pointers to the object. If you want otherwise, you will have to get into `Box` and `Pin`, which is kind of hard to stomach.

Comment: If you are dealing with pointers, you usually want stack objects that don't move at all. Ideally, as previously mentioned, something like `Box::pin()`. But that is highly error-prone territory where you should tread very carefully and ask yourself if pointers are really necessary.

Comment: Self-ref structs are almost impossible in Rust, even with `unsafe`. As mentioned, every object is trivially movable, so you have to always assume that the object got moved. Again, `Pin` combined with `PhantomPinned` might potentially help you out there.

Comment: @BiagioF There is not much resource on what you can or can't do in unsafe rust yet (WIP), https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html?highlight=pointer#behavior-considered-undefined https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/intro.html.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it always true that "print (1)" and "print (2)" are going to display two different address?

Unsure if it's always like this, but it's most certainly nowhere defined to be true, so a compiler implementation could always change this behaviour.

---

> In other words, move a value always implies the change of its address?

No, a move does not always imply a change of address. Compilers are allowed to optimize out unnecessary moves to my knowledge.

---

> Considering the new function returns Self. Is the correct terminology saying that "the returned value is moved"?

I think so, but I'm not an expert on terminology. A compiler expert might be able to add some information here.

---

> In other words, this is going to be moved to the caller function?
>
> In that case, why it seems that the address of this does not change? RVO is kicking in here?

I think so. I'd assume it's a case of what I previously stated: a compiler is allowed to optimize out unnecessary moves. Moves are transparent in Rust; they don't have any side effects, because they can't happen if someone holds a reference to an object; also they don't run any code, they are simply memcopies.

---

One important question you should ask yourself:

Would the situation be identical if you didn't `println!()` the addresses of the variables? Or could they have been further optimized, eliminating moves? Did the act of watching them influence the behaviour?

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm not an expert on this subject, that's just my understanding of how Rust works.

Comment: About the move to the caller, by terminology this is a move, but for big values the compiler actually implements this by taking a pointer to the caller's stack frame and writing directly there.